# C9510-401 IBM WAS Network Deployment V8.5.5 and Liberty Profile certification

Tags: websphere, middleware, websphere-liberty

Could anyone please help me with the resources from where I can prepare for C9510-401 IBM WAS Network Deployment V8.5.5 and Liberty Profile certification.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page [Certification overview, objectives, exam preparation and registration](https://www.ibm.com/training/certification/01007010) and in the ***Exam Resources*** section, you have all these subjects as links. Read them through. Also check ***Exam Objectives*** and study subjects you are not comfortable with.

```
* Dump Agent Env variables.

* GenPluginCfg command

* Multi-cell Performance management

* MustGather: Installation Manager issues for installing and updating WebSphere Application Server V8.0 and V8.5 , Section "Manually Collecting the files"

Multiple security domains

Virtual Hosts

Virtual hosts settings

fine-grained administrative authorization group

manageprofiles command

plugin-cfg.xml file

WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Concepts, Planning, and Design Guide

WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Administration and Configuration Guide for the Full Profile
```